# Fetch the data from second tables according to keys in 1st table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a database of the following from which I am able to fetch a single row by the following query:

```
Select Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5 from
tbData
WHERE
QueryParam1=@queryParam1 and QueryParam1=@queryParam2
```

to get the following output

```
Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5
  12      45     76       20     19
```

Now, the second table has the following detail:

```
SNo Detail
12   ABC
45   XYZ
76   ASD
20   GHY
19   GHJ
```

I have to fetch the columns such that the resultant table should be like

```
Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5
 ABC     XYZ     ASD     GHY     GHJ
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.Detail AS Item1,
       s2.Detail AS Item2,
       s3.Detail AS Item3,
       s4.Detail AS Item4,
       s5.Detail AS Item5
    FROM tbData d
        INNER JOIN SecondTable s1
            ON d.Item1 = s1.SNo
        INNER JOIN SecondTable s2
            ON d.Item2 = s2.SNo
        INNER JOIN SecondTable s3
            ON d.Item3 = s3.SNo
        INNER JOIN SecondTable s4
            ON d.Item4 = s4.SNo
        INNER JOIN SecondTable s5
            ON d.Item5 = s5.SNo
    WHERE QueryParam1 = @queryParam1 
      AND QueryParam2 = @queryParam2
```

Comment: If I have 10 items, and I do 10 inner joins, would that slow down the performace? Using 10 innter joins in a single query looks clean?

Comment: @Cipher As long as the column you're joining on , SNo, is indexed performance should not be an issue. As for "looking clean", use a good, consistent indenting style and your query should remain readable.